# Difference between NはNが多い and NounにNが多い

Tags: particle-に, particle-は, particle-が

この川にマスが多い。This river is full of trout.

新潟は雪が多い。 There’s much snow in Niigata

What’s the difference between に and は here ?

I learned only Noun1はNoun2がAdjい/な structure

Comment: "When it comes to Niigata, it snows a lot" vs "It snows a lot in Niigata". While the difference might not be that simple, I believe you shouldn't ovethink about it when you're a beginner. IMO

Answer (score 3):

The difference might be in the context. N1はN2が多い sounds like an explanation only for N1, while N1にN2が多い sounds like an explanation compared to several others.

> この川はマスが多い。
>   This river has a lot of trout (describing only for this river).
>
> この川にマスが多い。
>   *This* river has a lot of trout (compared to some other rivers).

But は is sometimes used to imply a comparison with others. It may depend on the context.